# How do I compose two deftypes into a new deftype when they all live in different files?

Tags: clojure, composition

The following works in the repl:

```
(defprotocol MyProtocol
  (foo [this]))
(deftype A []
  MyProtocol
  (foo [this] "a"))
(deftype B []
  MyProtocol
  (foo [this] "b"))
(deftype C []
  MyProtocol
  (foo [this] (str (foo (A.)) (foo (B.)))))
```

When I try to move each instance to a separate file to reduce coupling, then I get the following error on `C`: "Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context"

Sample layout:

```
;; my_protocol.clj
(ns my-protocol)
(defprotocol MyProtocol
  (foo [this]))

;; type_a.clj
(ns type-a
  (:require my-protocol :refer [MyProtocol])
(deftype A []
  MyProtocol
  (foo [this] "a"))

;; type_b.clj
(ns type-b
  (:require my-protocol :refer [MyProtocol])
(deftype B []
  MyProtocol
  (foo [this] "b"))

;; type_c.clj
(ns type-c
  (:import [type_a A]
           [type_b B])
  (:require my-protocol :refer [MyProtocol])
(deftype C []
  MyProtocol
  (foo [this] (str (foo (A.)) (foo (B.)))))
```

Comment: I think you meant *coupling*. You generally want to have high *cohesion* and low *coupling*. I can't test right now, but I would try first to fully qualify `foo`, e.g. `my-protocol/foo`.

Comment: Good point on cohesion/coupling.  Editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(ns type-a
  (:require my-protocol :refer [MyProtocol])
```

You refer to the protocol, but never to `foo`, so when you attempt to call `foo` the compiler doesn't know what you mean. Instead write:

```
(ns type-a
  (:require my-protocol :refer [MyProtocol foo])
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not very clear from most of the tutorials I've seen what your namespace looks like after you use defprotocol and deftype.  Do you have a link to a good one that we can add as a link for posterity?